# passing argument of text file from main to other function

Tags: c

How can I pass argument from cmd which is equal to the name of the file I want to open with other function than main?

I want to run program in cmd as "myprogram -open myfile.txt" just for example, and I want use another function to count characters or spaces or whatever in this file. How can I pass the name of file, which is in this case argv[2] to another function in which I can use fopen? thanks for your time.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
if((argc==3) && (strcmp("-open", argv[1]) == 0))
etc.
```

Comment: See how you're passing `"-open"` to `strcmp()`? Why would passing `argv[2]` to another function be any different? Are you asking how to *define* that other function?

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass in `argv[2]`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if((argc==3) && (strcmp("-open", argv[1]) == 0))
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen(argv[2]);
        //OR
        otherFuncThatCallsFopen(argv[2]);
    }
}
```

`argv[2]` is a valid `char *` that points to the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function with signature like `unsigned int count_characters(const char *file_name)`

and call it with `count_characters(argv[2])`